How do chess engines choose how long to analyse each move?
I understand the basics of chess engines (alpha beta pruning etc). But in a timed game, how do chess engines choose how long to analyse each move?

Time management is a part of competitive chess engines. Some of the considerations in allocating time to a move are discussed here. A related concept, Pondering is also discussed.
In short, chess engine time management functions on a collection of heuristics that have been developed over many decades. I do not believe there is a collective agreed-upon approach comparable to something like the alpha-beta pruning algorithm.
